# Keep everything inbetween quotations in an Excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file (xlsx) with one column and a thousand rows.

Example:

```
row A| oulzdwdwjdwojd=."A180202"wodwdojwdowj
row B| dwodjwodjwdowj-."N310302"wdwdwdwdwdw
row C| wdowduwoduwoduwdowudowudwoduwoduwdouw
row D| woduwoduwdowu-"N330201"
```

There is a lot of junk mixed in with asset numbers between quotations. I am needing to remove everything except for what's inside of the quotations. Leaving me with something like

```
row A| A180202
row B| N310302
row C| N330201
```

I am a complete beginner to VBS. I believe that I could write a program to do this in C++ or Java but do not know how to complete such a task with VBScript that is part of Excel. I have obtained similar results using the Excel tools in the GUI but nothing that leaves me with exactly what I need.

How would I go about doing something like this in VBScript? I would guess I have to use a delimiter with left, right or replace.

Comment: Which parts do you have written already? Will there only be a single asset number in each row?

Comment: use Regex: https://regex101.com/r/mF7bR2/1

Comment: Also, do you mean VBS or VBA? It sounds like you're talking about VBA...

Comment: VBA it would seem - thank you for clearing that up. There will only ever be one asset per row, sometimes there wont even be an asset in a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do you:

***VBA***

```
Sub SO()

Dim RE As Object, i As Long
Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

With RE
    .Pattern = """.*"""
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
End With

For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If RE.Test(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
        With Cells(i, 1)
            .Value = Replace(RE.Execute(.Value)(0), """", "")
        End With
    Else
        Cells(i, 1).ClearContents
    End If
Next

Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp

End Sub
```

`VBScript.RegExp` is just a Regular Expression engine that allows you to match patterns in a string (I'd be surprised if you haven't come across this before in C++ or Java...). You can set a reference to this but for ease I've gone with the late-binding option.

To try and explain, the code is looping through each cell in column A and performing a RegEx test against it. If the pattern matches, it replaces the value of the cell with the match - if the pattern *doesn't* match then it clears the contents of the cell.

Finally, we use Excel's `SpecialCells` method to identify any blank cells in column A and at the same time delete the row that they belong to.

If it makes it easier, the loop in Java would probably look something like this I imagine:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 1000; i++){
    if(RE.Test(Excel.Workbooks.ActiveWorkbook.Cells(i, 1).Value2)){
        // Blah blah....
    }
}
```

*(I don't write Java in case you haven't noticed...)*

Comment: thank you very much, your first solution worked beautifully. I will study it to understand what is being done. Just need to brush up on some of the syntax.

Comment: @SeanDiRienzo I've removed the VBS code and tried to explain what's happening so that you can understand some of it...

Answer (score 0):

The following is written in VBA. For VBS you'll just need to change the Range references, and put it in a loop:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim startQuote
    Dim endQuote
    startQuote = InStr(Range("A1").Value, """")
    endQuote = InStr(startQuote + 1, Range("A1").Value, """")
    Range("B1").Value = Mid(Range("A1").Value, startQuote + 1, endQuote - startQuote - 1)
End Sub
```

`InStr` is used to find the position of the first and second quote, `Mid` is used to extract the text between the quotes.

The double quote needs to be quoted, which is why there are four quotes.

Comment: I may be wrong, but by inspection this would crash on row C as it does not contain quotes.

Comment: I understand what is being done here, but I cannot get it to work. I alt+F11, insert module and use that code. I get an error on the last line.

Comment: @DeanOC You are right of course, but the OP could add IF statements to the code. But others are happy to provide full-coded solutions ;)

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you mean VBA...)

Add a reference to the `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` library and you can use a regex to extract the asset ID. This assumes you have a single asset ID in column A, per row, and it will will put the extracted ID into column B.

```
Public Sub DoIt()

    Dim re As New RegExp
    re.Pattern = """([^""]+)"""

    Dim intRow As Long
    For intRow = 1 To 1000
        If re.Test(Cells(intRow, 1)) Then
            Cells(intRow, 2) = re.Execute(Cells(intRow, 1))(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```